# CSS, Rotate Marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a rotate marquee, [this is the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdVnJ.jpg) , from reference the red line and blue line animation are running seamlessly. I have try to create my own, but the animation position run away

```css
.roll{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
    color:#000;
  }
  
  
@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
      -moz-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(6deg);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(6deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(6deg);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(6deg);
  }
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
      -moz-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(6deg);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(6deg);
      transform: translateX(100%) rotate(6deg);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(6deg);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(6deg);
      transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(6deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="roll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.></div>
```

[image: Reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a slight larger `width`(here `150vw`) than the screen and than `translate` from `0` to that extra `width`(`150vw`-`100vw`)

> Also you can use a extra container and `rotate` it `6deg` to remove a glitch kind of effect when animation restarts

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.roll {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 150vw;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
  color: #000;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.roll1 {
  transform: rotate(6deg);
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="roll1">
  <div class="roll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.></div>
</div>
```